# Error with installing additional package

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all )))

Sorry, if my question have been repeated but I haven't found the solution(
I was trying to install gmapping package but the error was.

I wrote this

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-gmapping
```

and I got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-gmappin
```

Why did the package not be installed?

Thank you very much))))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319971/error-with-installing-additional-package/) by [GlebCom](https://answers.ros.org/users/40667/glebcom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`gmapping` has not been released into Melodic, so that's why you can't install it using `apt-get`.

See #q303253, #q296170 and [wiki/slam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping). Notice how the wiki page has no version button for `melodic`. The [status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=gmapping) for Melodic also doesn't show any `gmapping` packages (meaning it hasn't been released).

As far as I understand there are also no plans to release it for Melodic. I can't find a reference, but I believe the idea is that other packages (such as Google's Cartographer) are much more powerful and feature complete, or at least much better maintained.

If you really want/need `gmapping` on Melodic, you could attempt a from-source build.

You may refer to #q300480 for a workflow that resulted in a successful build at the time the answer was written.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1